# Write 1 element of my list in a string, handle it and repeat this until I'm through the list

Tags: c#, string, list

I want to take one element from my list, give it to a method that works with it, then take the next element from my list until I am throught the whole list. The problem is that it still underlines the part after "_rawText = [here]" and I don't know what wrong. It says there are invalid arguments. I'm that far so far:

```
        string _rawText = "";
        List<string> _fileNameList = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < _fileNameList.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nDocument " + (i+1) +" of " + _fileNameList.Count + "\n");

                _rawText = ReadDocument(_fileNameList[i].ToString());

                CheckDocument(_rawText);

                AnalyzeResult();

                PrintResult();
            }

public string ReadDocument(List<string> _fileNameList)
        {
            if (File.Exists(_rawText))
            {
                return File.ReadAllText(_rawText);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine("\nKeine Datei gefunden!\n");
                Console.ResetColor();

                Console.WriteLine("Soll eine Textdatei unter folgendem Pfad erstellt werden? < j / n >");
                Console.WriteLine("Pfad: \"" + _rawText + "\"");

                string createFile = "";

                do
                {
                    createFile = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper().Trim();
                    switch (createFile)
                    {
                        case "J":
                            Console.Write("Datei wird erstellt...");

                            File.Create(_rawText());

                            if (!File.Exists(_rawText))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Datei konnte nicht ertellt werden.");
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("\nDatei wurde erfolgreich erstellt.");
                                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
                                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                                Console.WriteLine("Hinweis:");
                                Console.ResetColor();
                                Console.WriteLine("Bitte den zu überprüfenden Text in die Datei schreiben und das Programm erneut starten.");
                                break;
                            }
                        case "N":
                            Console.WriteLine("Programm wird beendet . . .");
                            Thread.Sleep(350);
                            Environment.Exit(0);
                            break;
                        case "LOL":
                            while (true)
                                Console.Write("LOL---");
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("");
                            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                            Console.WriteLine("Falsche Eigabe. Bitte gültigen Buchstaben eingeben. < j / n >");
                            Console.ResetColor();
                            Console.WriteLine("");
                            break;
                    }
                } while (createFile != "J" && createFile != "N");

                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It seems like you already know what to do? You've created a for loop and are iterating through it. What is your question? What is it not doing that you want it to do?

Comment: Sorry, should've mentioned it. The problem is that it still underlines the part after "_rawText = [here]" and I don't know what wrong. It says there are invalid arguments.

Comment: So what is the signature for ReadDocument? And you don't need .ToString(), it's already a string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is ReadDocument accepts a List of string, and you're passing in just a string. But the method doesn't use that parameter anyway. It's using _rawText, which isn't defined in method. Seems like you got multiple problems here. But your initial problem is passing a string when a `List<string>` is required.

Comment: Can u tell me which value my program expects here in my ReadDocument method? `Console.Write("Datei wird erstellt..."); 
File.Create(_fileNameList[ HERE ]);
if (!File.Exists(_fileNameList))`

Answer (score 1):

Your `ReadDocument()` method expects a full List as a parameter, but you are passing a string instead. Based on the code in your loop, you should change the signature of `ReadDocument()` to receive a string instead:

```
public string ReadDocument(string fileName)
{
    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        return File.ReadAllText(fileName);
    }
    else
    {
       //...
    }
}
```